# How to linearize a chain of if-then constraints?

Tags: constraint, linearization

How can I express the process of converting a series of if-then constraints into a linear form?

Let's assume that we have integer variable $x_i$, non-negative variables $y_i^d$, and binary variables $\delta_{i,j}^d$. Additionally, we assume that N and S are natural numbers, and A and B are subsets of all links $(i,j) \in E$, where A and B represent links that do not intersect.

The conditional statements:

If $x_i \geq N  $ then The $\delta_{i,j}^d = 1  $ or $ \delta_{i,j}^d = 0$. but if $\delta_{i,j}^d = 1$ I want to ensure that  $ y_i^d \leq y_j^d - S  \quad \forall (i,j) \in A$

But If $x_i < N  $ I want to ensure that $\delta_{i,j}^d=0 \quad  \forall (i,j) \in A$ but they could take value fron set$B$. in other words,   $\delta_{i,j}^d =0 $ or $ \delta_{i,j}^d =1 \quad \forall (i,j)\in B $
And if this latter happen $  y_i^d \leq y_j^d - N \cdot S \quad \forall (i,j)\in B $

Comment: Be careful: $$p \implies q \implies r,$$ $$p \implies (q \implies r),$$ and $$(p \implies q) \land (q \implies r)$$ mean three different things.  I think you meant the last one.

Comment: If $\delta^d_{i,j}$ is a binary variable, then $\delta^d_{i,j} \le 1$ is always true.

Comment: Thanks very much for the heads up @RobPratt. I've been thinking why the first two are diffrenet? And Yes, For $A$  I want to ensure if $x>N$ then $\delta$ could be one and if ever $\delta$ take a value of one then $y$ to be calculated like that

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I had misplaced the parentheses in the second one.  I meant $(p \implies q) \implies r$.

Comment: Please edit your question to write the two desired implications separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(i,j)\in A$, you want to enforce
$$\delta_{i,j}^d = 1 \implies y_i^d \le y_j^d - S \tag1\label1$$
and
$$x_i < N  \implies \delta_{i,j}^d=0 \tag2\label2$$
For $(i,j)\in B$, you want to enforce
$$\delta_{i,j}^d =1 \implies y_i^d \le y_j^d - N \cdot S \tag3\label3$$

To enforce \eqref{1}, use big-M:
$$y_i^d - y_j^d + S \le M(1-\delta_{i,j}^d) \quad \text{for $(i,j)\in A$}$$
To enforce \eqref{2}, first rewrite as its contrapositive:
$$\delta_{i,j}^d=1 \implies x_i \ge N$$
and then use big-M:
$$N - x_i \le M(1-\delta_{i,j}^d) \quad \text{for $(i,j)\in A$}$$
To enforce \eqref{3}, use big-M:
$$y_i^d - y_j^d + N\cdot S \le M(1-\delta_{i,j}^d) \quad \text{for $(i,j)\in B$}$$
Note that the values of $M$ are different in these three cases.  In each case, $M$ should be a (small) constant upper bound on the LHS when $\delta_{ij}^d=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for detialed explanation @RobPratt it cleared things up in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

If the binary variable $\delta_{i,j}^d$ is defined to linearize, Your first clause can be converted as:

$$Iff \quad ((x_i \geq N) \implies \delta_{i,j}^d = 1)) \quad \implies ((\delta_{i,j}^d = 1) \implies y_i^d \leq y_j^d - S) $$ is equal to:

$$Iff \quad ((\delta_{i,j}^d = 0) \implies x_i \leq N) \quad \implies ((\delta_{i,j}^d = 1) \implies y_i^d \leq y_j^d - S) $$

It yields the following linear constraints:

$$ x_{i} \leq N + M_{1}\delta_{i,j}^d \quad (1)$$
$$ y_{i} - y_{j} + S\leq M_{2}(1-\delta_{i,j}^d) \quad (2)$$

For the second clause, the procedure is the same.

Comment: thanks. But if $\delta =0$ then $x$ nust be less than N, but in here it become equal too

Comment: I am not sure understanding your comment well, but in the first, you want x>N if delata=1 which is equal to if delta=0 then x<N. In the second, the condition is reversed. In that you want x<N if delta = 0 which is equal to if delta=1 then x>N.

Comment: In my first linear constraint if delta =0 then x<n.

Answer (score 1):

Going by @Omidi answer, constr (1) solves your problem for $N \lt x$ but to achieve $\delta =1 $ for $ x=N$ you can try\

$N - M\alpha - M\delta \le x \le N + M\delta - \epsilon\alpha$
$\delta + \alpha \le 1 $
where $0 \le \epsilon \lt \min (\vert x-N \vert)$
This makes $\delta$ free for $x\lt N$

So $ x\lt N$ define another binary $\beta$ as
$ N \le x + M\beta$
$ \epsilon\beta -M(1-\beta) \le N-x$